# On Wix is there a way to disable the ellipsis that shows when you make a collapsible text box? Transferring site to EditorX?

Tags: velo

A client wants me to remove the ellipsis that shows up when you make a text box collapsible. I see on the documentation that there is a way to disable the ellipses but it seems to disable the collapsible function entirely.

I tried to transfer a copy of the site over to EditorX so that I would have more flexibility but it appears Wix has disabled that feature, so if anyone has suggestions on a workaround for that it would also be helpful. Thanks.

Here’s a link to the documentation. https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/breadcrumbs/hideellipsis

I’ve tried disabling the ellipsis which does remove it, but also removes the collapsible function entirely.